# Scraping the attribute of the first child from multiple div (selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, parent-child

I'm trying to scrap the class name of the first child (span) from multiple div.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="ui_column is-9">
   <span class="name1></span>
   <span class="...">...</span>
   ...
<div class ="ui_column is-9">
   <span class="name2></span>
   <span class="...">...</span>
   ...
<div class ..
```

[URL](https://www.tripadvisor.fr/Restaurant_Review-g187147-d9806534-Reviews-ASPIC-Paris_Ile_de_France.html) of the page for the complete code.

I'm achieving this task with this code for the first five div:

```
i=0
liste=[]

while i <= 4: 

    parent= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui_column is-9']")[i]    
    child= parent.find_element_by_xpath("./child::*")                              
    class_name= child.get_attribute('class')                                  
    i = i+1
    liste.append(nom_classe)
```

But do you know if there is an easier way to do it ?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the _classname_ _`ui_bubble_rating bubble_50`_

Comment: Exactly, I'm interrested by the number following "bubble_"  (bubble_XX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly get all these first `span` elements and then extract their `class` attribute values as following:

```py
liste = []
first_spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui_column is-9']//span[1]")
for element in first_spans:
    class_name= element.get_attribute('class')
    liste.append(class_name)
```

You can also extract the `class` attribute values from 5 first elements only by limiting the loop for 5 iterations
**UPD**
Well, after updating your question the answer becomes different and much simpler.
You can get the desired elements directly and extract their class name attribute values as following:

```py
liste = []
first_spans = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui_column is-9']//span[contains(@class,'ui_bubble_rating')]")
for element in first_spans:
    class_name= element.get_attribute('class')
    liste.append(class_name)
```

Comment: Thanks you ;)  
But, in my case, your solution also scrap the child of the child.

Comment: I built the XPath according to the XML structure you presented in the question. Here the first child `span` has no children, however the second `span` has children, by we don't care about that. In case the actual XML structure is different please update your question

Comment: I update my post with the URL of the page I'm scrapping. The class name of the parent div is the same as in the simplified code I shared previously.

Comment: OK, I see. Please see my updated answer